# My ios device could not connect to my pptpd

Tags: ios, vpn, pptp

Here is the log of pptpd

```
pptpd-logwtmp: $Version$
using channel 114
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xe78e1856> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x293c2339> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x293c2339> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xe78e1856> <pcomp>  <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xe78e1856> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x293c2339> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x293c2339> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xe78e1856> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xe78e1856]
peer refused to authenticate: terminating link
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "peer refused to authenticate"]
rcvd [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x293c2339]
rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "MPPE required but not available"]
sent [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
Hangup (SIGHUP)
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

here are the config of pptpd

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
debug
proxyarp
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
logfile /var/log/pptpd.log
```

I have tried to disabled the `mppe-128` but it didn`t work 
and my windows8.1 client and Android device could connect with my pptpd server 
my pptpd is running on the ubuntu 14.04 X64 . 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

thisis my pptpd-options file.  i have no problems connecting with ios
give it a try :)

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```